# Is there a way to show line numbers in .cshtml file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, numbers, line

I am using VS2012 ultimate and already clicked "show line numbers" option from text editor. VS2012 shows line numbers in models and controllers.

I know there is a way you can show line numbers with notepad++ or browser's source code. But copy, paste and search line number process is giving waste of time and also you can't do commands like "go to definition", "peek definition" vs.

Due to these reasons, I want to show line numbers in .cshtml file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using VS2013, there you have an option for each individual extension. So look for .(cs)html files and see if there is a "show line numbers".

Comment: Can you be more specific? did you do right click on .(cs)html or did you go to tools, options vs.

Comment: Tools > options > Text Editor > HTML > Line numbers

Comment: Thanks for reply. That solved the issue. if i had enough rep, i could give you a vote up. Site rules Sorry!

Comment: @Triplus You'd better edit the answer and delete the comment

Answer (score 6):

In VS go to Menu:  `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> General -> Settings` then check the option stating `Line Numbers`

Answer (score 4):

Go to: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor And For Every file extension you want to have numbers you have to mark Line Numbers [image]